# Plotly - update subplot titles after traces where createtd

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly plot composed of subplots -

```
fig = make_subplots(
        rows=3, cols=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=3, col=1)
```

I was to add a title for every the subplots but only after the figure is created and the traces are added. I.e not when I create the figure -

```
fig = make_subplots(
            rows=3, cols=1, subplot_titles=['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Can I do it via `fig.update_layout` or something similar?

Comment: maybe a better structure could be https://plotly.com/python/figure-factories/

Comment: plus it seems a structural problem: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2483#issuecomment-630889399

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `make_subplots` is used it's creating (correctly placed) annotations.  So this can be *mostly* duplicated using annotation methods.  In general, for the first:

```
fig.add_annotation(xref="x domain",yref="y domain",x=0.5, y=1.2, showarrow=False,
                   text="a", row=1, col=1)
```

The downside is you may need to adjust `x` and `y` to your conditions/tastes.

Full example, using bold text:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)
    
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_annotation(xref="x domain",yref="y domain",x=0.5, y=1.2, showarrow=False,
                   text="<b>Hey</b>", row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_annotation(xref="x domain",yref="y domain",x=0.5, y=1.2, showarrow=False,
                   text="<b>Bee</b>", row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=3, col=1)
fig.add_annotation(xref="x domain",yref="y domain",x=0.5, y=1.2, showarrow=False,
                   text="<b>See</b>", row=3, col=1)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the xaxes as follows. This sets the x axis title on each subgraph:

```py
for i in range(3):
    fig['layout'][f'xaxis{i+1}'].update(title=f'Title {i+1}')
```

Related question setting `showgrid` on each axis:
[Plotly set showgrid = False for ALL subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67459925/plotly-set-showgrid-false-for-all-subplots)

Answer (score 0):

Specify anything for a title during make_subplot, as long as it is not an empty string. This will take care of calculating the right x and y for the annotation so that you don't have to figure it out yourself like in @jayveesea answer.

You only have to change the text of the title later on when it suits you.

The title of subplot is actually annotation **"text"**. Just in case you were not seeing word title anywhere. :-)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, subplot_titles=[" ", " ", " "])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=1, col=1)
fig.layout.annotations[0].update(text="My Title 1")

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=2, col=1)
fig.layout.annotations[1].update(text="My Title 2")

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]), row=3, col=1)      
fig.layout.annotations[2].update(text="My Title 3")

fig.show()
```

[image: Example with several subplots]

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=20), paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue", xaxis_title='X Label Name', yaxis_title="Y Label Name")
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to update the title of each subplot, not the axis titles.